# Action recognition using video stream data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

Recently, I am working on an action recognition project where my input data is from the video stream. I read some of the concepts like ConvLstm, Convolutional Lstm, etc. I am looking for someone who already those kinds of staff already and can share his work with me that will be a really good help for me?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build a stream recognition pipeline than you can use OpenCV, Kafka, and Spark together.[how to build pipeline of video stream](https://www.infoq.com/articles/video-stream-analytics-opencv/)

and for Action recognition using ConvLstm. This link will help you.[action recognition using Convlstm](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Action-Recognition)